# How can i run flask wsgi app with apache on port :5000

Tags: apache

I am trying to deploy flask app like api on :5000 port(returning jsons).
What am i doing wrong?(it is not working).

My .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:5000>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/photochooser/app.wsgi
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        <Directory flaskapp>
             WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
             WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
             Order deny,allow
             Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then im typing a2ensite ....conf, restarting apache
And ip:5000 returning "Page not found"

P.S. its working on :80, but i need this port for my react client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found solution by myself:

Edited /etc/apache2/ports.conf:
Added ''' Listen 5000 '''

And then ip:5000 started working :)

Comment: Awesome job finding the answer yourself.  You should mark it as the answer so everyone knows it is.  :)